# Any control or library to provide ability of visually editing PDFs in our application?

Tags: .net

First off, we're not trying to build a PDF editor. We just want an enhancement in our software to allow users to edit PDFs that they are already storing in our software. How can this be implemented without launching external app like Adobe Acrobat?
We've tried Tx Text Control, but it is best suited for Word files, not PDF. Importing PDF into that control is always lossy.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

You can achieve something similar by using **[Ghostscript](http://ghostscript.com/)** or **[muPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/)** to render your PDF to the screen, **[GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** to allow user to draw over rendered PDF, **[iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)** to translate GDI+ objects to PDF objects.

Everything I mentioned is doable, only thing that will take some time to implement is removing existing PDF objects from the existing PDF document, but this can be also done.

If you need the **Ghostscript wrapper for .NET** take a look here: **http://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com**

Recently I wrote a blog about how to use iTextSharp to manipulate PDF objects in existing PDF document. That should be a good start point for you as it shows how to parse PDF page content bytes, change PDF objects, build new content bytes, override content with new content bytes: **[Converting PDF files to Grayscale by using iTextSharp](http://habjan.blogspot.com/2013/09/proof-of-concept-converting-pdf-files.html)**